# my RAM gets full and PC crashes when i execute my python script .

Tags: python, memory, crash, overflow, ram

I wrote a simple script in python . It's a talking battery monitor , inspired from IronMan Jarvis . Now the problem is that , the code runs perfectly but the RAM keeps getting full when the code is running . Finally when the RAM gets full , the PC crashes . What could be the problem? I dont use any new varibles . I update the same variable by polling . This is my code-

```
# Get power status of the system using ctypes to call GetSystemPowerStatus

import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import speech

def startmonitor():   
    class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
                    ('ACLineStatus', wintypes.BYTE),
                    ('BatteryFlag', wintypes.BYTE),
                    ('BatteryLifePercent', wintypes.BYTE),
                    ('Reserved1', wintypes.BYTE),
                    ('BatteryLifeTime', wintypes.DWORD),
                    ('BatteryFullLifeTime', wintypes.DWORD),
                   ]
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P = ctypes.POINTER(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS)
    GetSystemPowerStatus = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetSystemPowerStatus
    GetSystemPowerStatus.argtypes = [SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS_P]
    GetSystemPowerStatus.restype = wintypes.BOOL

    status = SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS() #define an object of the class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS
    if not GetSystemPowerStatus(ctypes.pointer(status)):
        raise ctypes.WinError()
    return status
x=0  #counting variable
def setflag0():
    for x in range(7):
        flag[x]=0
    return flag

def setxval():

    if(status.BatteryLifePercent==100):
        x=0
    elif(status.BatteryLifePercent<100 and status.BatteryLifePercent>30):
        x=1
    elif(status.BatteryLifePercent<=30 and status.BatteryLifePercent>15):
        x=2
    elif(status.BatteryLifePercent<=15 and status.BatteryLifePercent>5):
        x=3
    elif(status.BatteryLifePercent<=5):
        x=4
    return x
flag=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
speech.say("This is the talking battery monitor version 1.0")
while(1) :
    status=startmonitor()
    bat=setxval()
    if(bat!=0 and status.ACLineStatus==1 and flag[1]!=1):
        speech.say("All power systems being charged sir ! ")
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[1]=1
    elif(bat==0 and flag[6]!=1):
        if(status.ACLineStatus==1):
            speech.say("Battery : one hundred percent charged")
        elif(status.ACLineStatus==0):
            speech.say("Sir , You have full battery power")
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[6]=1
    elif(bat==1 and status.ACLineStatus==0 and flag[2]!=1):
        speech.say("Battery Level : ")
        speech.say(status.BatteryLifePercent)
        speech.say("percent")
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[2]=1
    elif(bat==2 and flag[3]!=1 and status.ACLineStatus==0):
        speech.say("Sir, i'm running low on battery . Please put me on charge !" )
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[3]=1
    elif(bat==3 and flag[4]!=1 and status.ACLineStatus==0):
        speech.say("Sir, you're now running on emergency backup power")
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[4]=1
    elif(bat==4 and flag[5]!=1 and status.ACLineStatus==0):
        speech.say(" Alert ! Power critical Sir, I might turn off in ")
        speech.say(status.BatteryLifeTime/1000000)
        speech.say("minutes")
        flag=setflag0()
        flag[5]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the loop a function is using memory.

It might be that the system call  SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS is using memory.
Is it possible to call

```
status=startmonitor()
```

before the while loop?

Otherwise start removing code (even though it breaks the functionality temporarily) to find out which part uses memory and try to find an alternative for that part.